# Looking for Liveness recognition and face match API

Tags: face-recognition, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm coding an app with ReactNative and I'm looking for an API which will allow user to take a selfie from the app in order to compare the picture of the selfie with other pictures added previously by the user from his device to certified that the same person between the selfie and other pictures added from the device.

Could Google Cloud Vision API do this? I found anything about face recognition in their API documentation.

What are your recommandation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Google Cloud Vision API primarily focuses on image analysis tasks such as **label detection**, **object detection**, and **text recognition**. While it can detect faces in images, it doesn't provide [face recognition](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/features-list#:%7E:text=Specific%20individual%20Facial%20Recognition%20is%20not%20supported.) or facial verification capability. To achieve the kind of facial verification you're looking for, where you compare a selfie to other pictures added by the user, you'll need a facial recognition or verification service by using other tools or services(not GCP), or open-source libraries.